# My script does not working correctly it starts and not stop after it

Tags: php, function

I am working on a function, but that function is not working properly when 
I run it, then it runs continuously.

I didn't find where is actual problem is.

```
<?php  

    function recursion($a) {

        if($a < 20) {   
            echo "$a\n";    
            recursion($a);
        }

    }  

    $a = 2; 
    recursion($a);      
    echo "</br>";  

?>
```

Comment: As long as `2 < 20` you print 2 and you call the function again. <- You never change that 2 (`$a`). So why should the function end?

Comment: Q1: What is the condition for it to stop ? A1: because `$a` reaches 20. Q2: How will it reach 20 ?  A2: ... answering it will solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your recursion function going to infinite because you are passing same value again and again with `recursion($a);` so `if($a<20)` will be always result `true` and recursion won't break ever.

Try increment `++$a` or `$a += 1` or `$a = $a+1`.

```
recursion(++$a);//increasing value with prefix operator ++
```

Complete code:

```
function recursion($a) {
    if($a < 20) {   
        echo "$a\n";    
        recursion(++$a);
    }
}  
$a = 2; 
recursion($a);      
echo "</br>";
```

Output:

> 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Comment: Although this is a legit answer, you may want to explain it a bit for OP, he's clearly new at this.

Comment: Updated answer @Andrew. I think this is enough for OP to understand.